# Character Count includes whitespace

Tags: bug, comments

I noticed this a while ago, but didn't report it until now.

[image: 12 more characters to go]

Okay, that looks right.

[image: NOPE.AVI]

The thing under the comment doesn't say I need more characters, but when I try to submit it, I get an error.

Not a terrible bug, but still a weird thing.

Comment: wat[.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5736/unacceptably-inconsistent-comment-length-notifications)

Comment: There's nothing inconsistent here. Posts and comments automagically cull any white space. The character counter counts exactly what's in the box, then the post is processed before posting (which culls the excess white space), then the post is re counted to make sure it is still valid. Where it finds that it no longer is.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It shouldn't be that difficult to trim the contents before counting it.

Answer (score 4):

This is the result of too many people exploiting Unicode codepoints and spacing to get around the 15 characters: the site does more thorough length checking than the client-side javascript does.

This has the effect of making gaming the system slightly more inconvenient.